How can I hide a menuitem at odoo
I'm trying to hide a menuitem for all the user at crm module in odoo 17, with id res_partner_menu_customer, this is located at crm/views/crm_menu_viewls.xml
This is the original xml code
<menuitem
    id="res_partner_menu_customer"
    name="Customers"
    parent="crm_menu_sales"
    action="base.action_partner_form"
    sequence="5"/>

And I tried this
<odoo>
<data>
    <menuitem
    id="viva_res_partner_menu_customer"
    parent="crm.res_partner_menu_customer"
    name=""
    />
</data>

But it didn't works, I used active False but I have no results

To make it visible only for ADMIN, you can use groups="base.group_system":
<menuitem groups="base.group_system"
    id="res_partner_menu_customer"
    name="Customers"
    parent="crm_menu_sales"
    action="base.action_partner_form"
    sequence="5"/>

To make it visible only in debug mode (=activated developer mode / url+?debug=1), you can use groups="base.group_no_one":
<menuitem groups="base.group_no_one"
    id="res_partner_menu_customer"
    name="Customers"
    parent="crm_menu_sales"
    action="base.action_partner_form"
    sequence="5"/>

Better practices are:

to override it using its original id: "crm.res_partner_menu_customer"
to inherit the view and to add this attribute using xpath (in Back-office or using your custom module)...
More: Odoo: How to inherit menu items (make menu items invisible)


I have done something similar by overriding the IrUiMenu._filter_visible_menus
Something like this:
from odoo import api, models

class IrUiMenu(models.Model):
    _inherit = "ir.ui.menu"

    @api.returns('self')
    def _filter_visible_menus(self):
        """ Filter `self` to only keep the menu items that should be visible in
            the menu hierarchy of the current user.
            Uses a cache for speeding up the computation.
        """
        visible_menus = super(IrUiMenu, self)._filter_visible_menus()
        return visible_menus.filtered(lambda menu: menu.id != self.env["ir.model.data"]._xmlid_to_res_id("crm.res_partner_menu_customer"))



You can use this hide_menu_user extension

Please use this code to hide the menu for all users (Set active="False" attribute):
<menuitem id="res_partner_menu_customer" name="Customers" parent="crm_menu_sales" action="base.action_partner_form" sequence="5" active="False"/>
